# Change image color when app theme changed

Tags: image, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm writing an app in UWP (C# & XAML). I have this code:

```xml
<Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Image.svg"/> <!-- svg is preferred but not required -->
```

Image.svg is single color (black) image.
What I want to achieve is that the image changes color depending on the system/app theme (light theme = black image, dark theme = white image) without separated white and black image files.

At this moment, image is black.

Is it even possible?

I will appreciate any help and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change image color when app theme changed

For your requirement, we suggest you use  `BitmapIcon` to approach. And `BitmapIcon` has Foreground color property that you could set it dynamically when theme changed. And the other way is define different images for different themes, then binding image source with [`ThemeResource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/themeresource-markup-extension) markup.

For example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <BitmapIcon
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Foreground="{ThemeResource IconColor}"
        UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/Butterfly.png"
        Visibility="Visible" />
    <Image
        Grid.Row="1"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Source="{ThemeResource MyImage}" />

</Grid>
```

**Resource**

```
<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
        <ImageSource x:Key="MyImage">ms-appx:///Assets/png-icon.png</ImageSource>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IconColor" Color="Black" />
    </ResourceDictionary>

    <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
        <ImageSource x:Key="MyImage">ms-appx:///Assets/Butterfly.png</ImageSource>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="IconColor" Color="White" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
```